# How to check if a s3 bucket has an existing bucket policy using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have multiple s3 buckets. I want to apply a bucket policy on only those buckets which do not have an existing bucket policy.

Comment: [Retrieve the bucket policy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-bucket-policies.html), check if it's empty, take an action.

Answer (score 0):

The steps would be:

- Call [`list_buckets()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_buckets) to obtain a list of buckets
- Loop through the buckets, then for each bucket:

  - Call [`get_bucket_policy()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_bucket_policy) to obtain the current policy
  - If appropriate, call [`put_bucket_policy()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_policy) to update the bucket poilcy

Comment: get_bucket_policy will throw an Exception if there is no policy.
You need to catch ClientError from botocore.client, and update the bucket policy from the exception handler.